# How to switch to workspace right by pressing [Super]+[L]

Tags: unity, 16.04, shortcut-keys

How do I set the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to have my workspace to switch to the right?

I have tried to change my shortcut in the settings, but it doesn't work.

After pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> my screen is locked.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: The shortcut assigned to `Super+l` is by default, to log out. Did you make sure you create the new one properly?

Comment: control-alt-{left/right/up/down}arrow is used to switch workspaces.

Comment: See below.  The "Start" or "Windows" key is called the "Super" key in Ubuntu...

Comment: 1. Yes, I create new for sure

2. Yes, I know about control-alt-{left/right/up/down}arrow, but I would like to make it vim-like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need the CompizConfig Settings Manager:

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt install compiz-plugins
```

Open CCSM by going to the dash and type: `ccsm`.
[image]

Click the CCSM icon and:

1. First you must disable the internal "Lock screen" from <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>:

   - Scroll down to <kbd>Ubuntu Unity Plugin</kbd> and click on it
   - In the general tab click on the second line on the button `<Super>L`
   - Disable + OK
   - Click Back
2. Now allow <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to be the viewport key switcher:

   - Go to <kbd>System Settings</kbd> then <kbd>Keyboard</kbd>, then the <kbd>Shortcuts</kbd> tab:
     [image: Keyboard settings shortcut tab]

and assign <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

### Done!  :-)