# How to switch workspace by pressing [Super]?

Tags: 14.04, unity, shortcut-keys

How do I set the keyboard shortcut [left <kbd>Super</kbd>]  keyboard button and [right <kbd>Super</kbd>] keyboard button to have my workspace to switch to the 1st and 2nd workspace ?

I have tried to change my shortcut in the settings, but it doesn't work.
Then I've tried as in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840502/how-to-switch-to-workspace-right-by-pressing-superl)
But this doesn't work too.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Checkout this question : http://askubuntu.com/questions/83176/how-do-i-quickly-switch-between-workspaces-in-unity ( Check all the answers  there).

Comment: @ankit7540 In my qusetion, I've written that I've read how to do it using  [Super]+[L]. But I want to do it using only [Super]. Left Super - for first workspace, and so on.

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv what happens when you press super? Does dash appear or nothing happens?

Comment: @shreyash-s-sarnayak nothing happens because I change it to do nothing using CompizConfig.

Comment: Ok. This is what I did. I changed `Switch to workspace 1` to `Left Super` in Keyboard settings (was `Super + Home`). Now when I press `Super` it switches to the 1st workspace and opens dash. @TarasYaremkiv

Comment: I understand, but you can try something like `Super+z` and `Super+/` which works without much issue.

Comment: @shreyash-s-sarnayak  in my case switching workspace  [Super] + [Home] doesn't work when I press only [Super] without [Home]

Comment: @ankit7540 if it's so hard to do it, I'll try to use "something like Super+z and Super+/" may be I'll like it